# Pandas error dividing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an odd situation in which pandas (assuming pandas, not Python) gives an inconsistent error. I am running Python 2.7.11 with Pandas 0.17.1 on a Windows 10 machine.

The basic error is this: if I have two df's with matched indexes and then simply do: dfA / dfB - 1, this calculation returns inconsistent errors if it is re-run many times.

Specifically:

```
import pandas as pd

close = pd.read_csv("C:\close.csv")
shifted = pd.read_csv("C:\shifted.csv")
ret = pd.DataFrame()

ret = shifted.C / close.C - 1
foo = min(ret)
bar = max(ret)
print "Starting with Max: %.4f Min %.4f" % (foo, bar)

for i in range(1000):
    ret = shifted.C / close.C - 1
    foo = min(ret)
    bar = max(ret)
    if foo < -.17 or bar > .16:
        print "Error on run %i: Max: %.4f Min %.4f" % (i, foo, bar)
```

I have .py and two csv's [at this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52la63rl48rsyoi/PossiblePandasBug.rar?dl=0).

Put the csv's in your C: root (or change code for file location elsewhere) and run the code. If it doesn't error, run it again and it likely will. Even the error frequency is inconsistent; sometimes it will error 20+ times in a thousand iterations, but usually only 1-2.

This seems like pretty basic functionality so I must be doing something wrong. This came out of a much larger project where I assumed it was do to Nan's being handled inconsistently, but this example shows that is not the case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Update:
per @EdChum's implied suggestion, updated Python to Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 15:00:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.

Pandas version is 0.17.1 and Numpy is 1.10.1.

Lest you think I'm crazy (I probably would if someone came to me with this error), here are the results from a few runs of the little program. Errors seem to be more rare, but they still happen.
[Errors on Windows 10 machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyqql.jpg)

Any thoughts? A memory issue of some type? What could cause an intermittent error in such a simple operation?

Update #2
Thinking this might be some kind of memory issue, so rewrote the code to simply count the number of errors in the operation. Got these highly suspicious results:

```
>85 errors in 20000 runs on 10100 dataframe rows
>144 errors in 20000 runs on 10001 dataframe rows
>0 errors in 20000 runs on 10000 dataframe rows
>0 errors in 20000 runs on 9999 dataframe rows
```

10,000 rows is not a lot, but it appears this is the issue? Is there some limitation in Pandas that I should be aware of?

Comment: I get no error on my machine running python 3.4.1, pandas 0.17.1, numpy  1.9.3 64-bit

Comment: Maybe try change `min(ret)` to `ret.min()` and `max` similar.

Comment: `In [68]: %timeit ret.min() -> 10000 loops, best of 3: 78.9 µs per loop`
`In [69]: %timeit min(ret) -> 1000 loops, best of 3: 781 µs per loop`

Comment: thanks for the speed note @jezrael. my "big code" used the pandas methods but I was avoiding them here for simplicity... they don't seem to be specifically relevant to the error, though?

Comment: I get no error, Python 2.7.6 Linux/Ubuntu, pandas 0.13.1, numpy 1.8.2

Comment: I dont know, but you can try it. What is size of your RAM?

Comment: @jezrael - Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, 8.00 GB. I will try some smaller csv's and see if I can find a window where they do not error. Regardless, it's not like this is a ton of data so I wouldn't think a memory issue normally.

Comment: I cannot replicate this error. Some ideas: 1. use `ret = shifted.C.div(close.C) - 1` instead of `ret = shifted.C / close.C - 1` 2. remove `ret = pd.DataFrame()` - ret will be `Series` 3. try `ret.min()` and `ret.max()`

Comment: @jazrael please see my edits re data length. I don't get an error if the df length is < 10,001 rows. How much memory do you have? Could you try /increasing/ the length of the dataset by copy/pasting the original csv's to make longer datasets and see if you have an error then? In practice, exceeding 10k rows is pretty common...

Comment: @jazrael your suggestions made sense. i tried them here https://www.dropbox.com/s/fo7l13bwidj9rps/Error3.py?dl=0 and still get errors. note that error frequency is between 0-50 errors per 10k runs so you might not see it in 1000 as the original post said. with a smaller dataset, i'm reducing error frequency but it should be perfectly consistent. thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by NumExpr, version 2.4.4.  We (Continuum) will be updating this package soon, which has been confirmed to fix this issue.  Until then, you can remove numexpr:

```
conda remove numexpr
```

See this related issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11743

EDIT: NumExpr 2.4.6 should now (01/14/16) be available.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and addressing this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with the Anaconda installation. Pure Python installation solves the problem on Windows. Scary bug. Everyone who looked at it--thank you for your help!